# Calculate speed an object is moving towards another direction

Tags: trigonometry

The title probably sucks because this is a really hard question to word properly, so I apologize for that.

Basically I have these two variables: `moveSpeed` and `moveDirection`. I'm using these to move an object at that speed in that direction. However, I want to find out how much of that speed is going in *another* direction.

So, for example

```
moveSpeed=10
moveDirection=80
otherSpeed=x
otherDirection=70
```

We have an object moving `80` degrees at `10` pixels per frame. How much of that speed is it moving `70` degrees? Also I realize (and expect) that this number will be negative when the direction is on the opposite side of the circle.

Also, here's a picture to make a little more sense.

[image]

Common sense tells us the speed is ~9 since the other direction is very close to the initial direction.

And if I still did too terrible of a job explaining, some static examples:

With `10 moveSpeed` in `0 moveDirection`, I'd get `-10 otherSpeed` at `180 otherDirection`

With `10 moveSpeed` in `0 moveDirection`, I'd get `0 otherSpeed` at `90 otherDirection`

With `10 moveSpeed` in `0 moveDirection`, I'd get `5 otherSpeed` at `45 otherDirection`

So, what formula would I plug `moveSpeed`, `moveDirection`, and `otherDirection` into to get `otherSpeed`?

Comment: Your intuition is pretty good, except that you would get `otherSpeed` of $10\cos45^\circ\approx7.071$ at `otherDirection = 45`. Imagine walking $10$ units along the diagonal of a $10$ unit square; you get farther than halfway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `the projection formula`. If you have a vector A and you want to find its projection vector on vector B then you use $S= {{A\cdot B}\over {B\cdot B}}  B$. Here $A$ is your original velocity vector $A=10(\cos80, \sin80)$. And $B$ is your new direction $B=(\cos70,\sin70)$. And the dot product is defined by $A\cdot B=a_1b_1+a_2b_2=10(\cos80\cos70+\sin80\sin70)$, which using a formula from trig is $10\cos(80-70)=10\cos10$. Your $B \cdot B$ is just $1$, as $B$ is a unit vector. So your velocity in the new direction is $10\cos10(\cos70,\sin70)$. Your speed in that direction is $10\cos10$.

Comment: So, in its simplest form, the formula I'd use would be moveSpeed*cos(moveDirection-otherDirection)? I ask since I'm using this in a program and it'd just be better for everything to use the simplest maths possible. Sorry for taking so long to respond also; I've been trying to wrap my head around your answer since I'm far from skilled in math ^^'

Comment: @fay Yes. That is the formula for the signed length of the projection. So a negative answer means backing up speed.